How to prevent re-render in React JS when a counter function in another component updates store? (zustand, immer)
I had many problems with re-Rendering (not with updating the DOM, that worked fine!) while working with useContext. Now i switched to 'zustand' and solved almost all my problems I had.
In my project I have a 'zustand' store which gets new informations from periodical fetching.
In another component I want to initially load the stored information when I navigate to that component and then store it in another position at the store.
But here the state variables seem to be always locked together.
For playing around,
I built an Codesandbox.io Zustand Immer Example  with all components (starting with a headline). For better visualisation install
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/react-devtools/
to see components highlighting if re-Rendered. (otherwise I also included a console.log)
Every 5 sec the "CircleComponent" will be updated (here set to ["yellow","blue","yellow"]).
It will only get re-rendered if the colors change, that's what I intended.
I can click on the "Editable Circles" and only this component re-renders. Then i click on "submit Colors" and then both color Component re-Render but only the top color-component one needs to re-render (first problem). Then after another 5 seconds, the default color is loaded and again both color components re-Render (second problem). The bottom one shouldn't need to re-render
Codesandbox.io Zustand Immer Example
best to view it in a browser and watch the log for component re-render or use react devtools plugin and switch on "Highlight updates when components render"
my example store looks something like that:
export const useAppStore = createWithEqualityFn<AppState>()(
  immer((set) => {    
    return {
      counter: 0,
      text: '',
      colorArray: ["red", "green", "blue"],  
};
  }),
  shallow
);

subscription in critical component "EditableCircleComponent.tsx":
const initialColors = useAppStore((state) => state.colorArray);
const setColorArray = useAppStore((state) => state.setColorArray);
const [localColors, setLocalColors] = useState(initialColors);

if i replace:
const initialColors = useAppStore((state) => state.colorArray);

with:
const initialColors = ["red", "green", "blue"]

of course no re-render will happen. If I chance the colors and they get resetted --> again no re-render. that's the behaviour I want but i need the initial colors from the store.
i wanted to have only minimal necesarry re-renders
